# PHP 7 como aplicar codificacion UTF-8 en mis resultados para que no salgan con signos raros

Tags: php, php7

tengo mi siguiente funcion:

```
function alimento_getAllByUser_orderByTipoAlimento($usuario){

    include_once 'conexion.php';

    if ($con = conectar()) {
        $sql = "  
                SELECT 
                    alimentos.id AS 'alimento_id' ,
                    alimentos.nombre AS 'alimento_nombre',
                    alimentos.cantidad AS 'alimento_cantidad',
                    alimentos.tipo AS 'tipo_alimento_id',
                    tipos_alimentos.nombre AS 'tipo_alimento_nombre'
                FROM 
                    alimentos,tipos_alimentos,usuarios  
                WHERE
                  alimentos.tipo = tipos_alimentos.id
                  AND 
                  tipos_alimentos.usuario = usuarios.id
                  AND 
                  usuarios.id = (SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = ?)
                ORDER  BY tipos_alimentos.nombre ASC;"

        ;

                    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
                        $stmt->bind_param("s",$usuario);
                        $stmt->execute();

                        $result = $stmt->get_result();

                            if ($result) {
                                $alimentos = array();
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                    //$alimentos = $row;
                                    array_push($alimentos, $row);

                                }

                                //return $nombre_usuario;
                                //var_dump($alimentos);
                                return $alimentos;

                            }


                        }
                        desconectar($con);

        }

        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Y quiero que se vean los caracteres bien, es decir, aplicar el `charset=UTF-8` para evitar resultados como este :

`'ba�o'` (*baño*)

He probado poniendo esto dentro de la funcion en la primera linea de la misma: 
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

pero nada, no me lo detecta con **utf-8**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo arregle!

Lo que hice para **solucionarlo** es irme a mi **conexion.php**

Yo tenia esto:

```
$con  = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

        if ($con) {
            return $con;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
```

Entonces le añadi justo despues de comprobar que la conexion fuese exitosa el encoding utf-8 usando la funcion `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");`. Quedando la **solucion** asi :

```
$con  = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

        if ($con) {
            mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
            return $con;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
```